# Is there a "nicer" way in Svelte to declare and update multiple variables from an exported prop?

Tags: svelte, destructuring

**Background**

I have a project for my company i'm working on.

We decided to use Svelte in this Project. We are monitoring information from an microservice in this application.

I have build a component which takes the information from an object named "value" and declares it's props with the destruction notation. This value will be updated. On every update the props of the "value" are used to do a computation with them and render the results or the props directly in the template.

Here is the source Code (unnecessary parts omitted):

```svelte
<script>

let state = "default";
let dayDiff = 0;
let dateOutput;
let valuesAvailable;

export let value;

let {name, finished, started, running, lastRun, completion, messages} = value;
$: {
 ;({name, finished, started, running, lastRun, completion, messages} = value)

 valuesAvailable = Object.keys(value).length > 0;
 if(selectedItemStore === name) {
   selectedItemStore.set(value)
 }

 if (valuesAvailable) {
   if (completion) {
     completion = Number(value.completion.slice(0, -1));
   } else {
     completion = 0;
   }
   const messageArray = Object.entries(messages);
   if (running) {
     state = 'running';
   } else {
     if (completion === 100) {
       state = 'done'
     }
     if (messageArray.length > 0) {
       state = "info";
     }
   }
   if (finished) {
     dateOutput = Utils.getRelOrAbsoluteDate(finished)
   } else if (running && started) {
     dateOutput = "running...";
   } else {
     state = "never-run";
     dateOutput = "Did not run before"
   }
   if (completion < 100 && !running && started) {
     state = 'error';
   }
 }
}
</script>

<div class={"item " + state + (selectedItemStore === value.name ? " selected" : "")} on:click={toggleSelection}>
 
 <span class="name">{name}</span>
 <iron-icon icon={iconMappings[state]}></iron-icon>
 {#if state!=='never-run'}
     <div class="bar">
         <CompletionIndicator value={completion}/>
     </div>
 {/if}
 <span class="date">
     {dateOutput}
 </span>
</div>
```

**The Problem**

These lines are problematic:

```svelte
<script>
    export let value;

    let {name, finished, started, running, lastRun, completion, messages} = value;
    $: {
        ;({name, finished, started, running, lastRun, completion, messages} = value)
    
        (...)
    }
</script>
```

Code inside of $: { ... } is executed each time the "value" changes. I do it this way because the "computation" has to be re-done on every render. Outside of the "reactive-function" the actual values are declared for the use in the template. They **must** be declared outside of the reactive-function scope, so they can be used in the actual Svelte-template.

**Conclusion**

This is working but not easy to read in the first place. I haven't found a solution yet to make it more readable and working.
A one-liner would be nice or another approach to this problem.
Have you any ideas?

**EDIT:**

We've found already a good solution marked as the accepted answer using the {#key value} syntax outside of this component.
Anyway, performancewise it would be smarter to use just [Sherif Salahs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68001532/13270233) solution with a reactive declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `#key` block to re-render the component you need the data to be dynamic in. This may be undesirable if you have transitions inside the component since they will need some workarounds to run properly inside a `#key` block, but it might help for your use case.

Here's a more simplified example where data in the parent changes and the component (with destructured object) re-renders to match the state in the parent without any reactive statements. And here's a [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/9bea8fa9846140d28444bece70fb7d27?version=3.38.2) to try out.

**App.svelte**

```svelte
<script>
    import Component from './Component.svelte'
    let value = {name: 'Creed Bratton', age: 30}
</script>

<input bind:value={value.name} />
<input type="number" bind:value={value.age} />

{#key value}
    <Component {value} />
{/key}
```

**Component.svelte**

```svelte
<script>
    export let value;
    let {name, age} = value
</script>

<div>
    <p>
        {name} - {age}
    </p>
    {#if age > 30}
        <p>Wow, that is old</p>
    {/if}
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if i'm getting it correctly. Are you indirectly stating that i should extract parts of my current component as an extra component, e.g. instead of <span class="date">{dateOutput}</span> use <Date value={someValue} /> ?

Comment: No, I'm assuming the code you shared is of a single component since you are `export let`ting and destructuring an object. I'm saying wherever **that** component is being used (like in App.svelte) you would wrap it in a `#key` block, key it to the value of `value` in the parent and all of it's contents will be re-rendered when the external value that it is keyed to changes.

Comment: To be clear, in my example Component.svelte represents the component code you shared, I don't know anything else about your app or how it's being used, so it's a contrived example.

Comment: Ah. I think i got it. It feels like if you're not answering the original question, but i think you're about to say to take the "$ { ... }" part out and just write a plain <script> part. Because if i use the {#key} syntax, the component will be forced to rerender. And if i leave the "$: {...}", there is no nead to declaring and updating the value manually. Correct?

Comment: Exactly, it moves the reactivity outside of the component so you can destructure the object in a single line inside the component without needing extra syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Split it up into two reactive statements like this:

```js
export let value;

$: ({name, finished, started, running, lastRun, completion, messages} = value);
$: {
    (...)
}
```

Comment: This approach is straigh forward and seems to be correct syntax wise. In the past i've allready tried it but IntellJ marked it as wrong. So theoretically it is working without a hassle on sveltes side. But the svelte-plugin for IntelliJ seems to be doing straight stuff there. Even if this solution is not 100% working for me, it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use a store if the props are too many, but in your case why not check the parent object itself for any changes:

```svelte
<script>
    export let value;
    $: if (value) {
        // do your magic
    }
</script>
```

and you can use `value.porp` directly whenever needed.

Comment: From react i've learned that it's good practice to destruct the object so you don't have to use many ```value.something``` calls. So it's not really a solution to the original problem but a "move" to another problem that is solved by the object destruction.

Comment: from my knowledge there is no shorter way if you don't wanna use `value.prop` .. but about reactivity use the suggested part ` $: if (value)` to check any changes in the whole object.